# Piping output from GitHub clone using tee misses output

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, pipe, io-redirection

I thought I would log the output of cloning a GitHub repo to a file. If I run

```
git clone git@github.com:my_repo/my_repo.git | tee -a log
```

I get an empty `log` file, but the following output to the command line:

```
Cloning into 'my_repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 284, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (228/228), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (133/133), done.
remote: Total 284 (delta 122), reused 162 (delta 69), pack-reused 56
Receiving objects: 100% (284/284), 873.22 KiB | 2.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (138/138), done.
```

which is already a little mysterious to me. I figured that I should try to pipe both `stderr` and `stdout` to the file with

```
git clone git@github.com:my_repo/my_repo.git 2>&1 | tee -a log
```

and now both the `log` file and the command line get

Cloning into 'my_repo'...

What am I missing here? How do I get the `remote: ...` lines into a file with `tee`?

Comment: It's possibly because git adjusts its verbosity when not writing to an interactive terminal - see for example [Git clone verbose output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056130/git-clone-verbose-output)

Comment: As steeldriver say, it detects if output is to a `tty` or not. You will get a lot of gobbledygook using `--progress` as it overwrites the same line over and over while *progressing*. A simple `cat` of the file wil look OK, but the file itself will have all the extra lines. Post processing the output with `sed 's/.*\r//'` should fix most of it. Optionally piping it before tee, but then you will loose the interactive progress count. `git clone --progress path/to/repo.git.git 2>&1 | sed 's/.*\r//' | tee log`

Comment: @steeldriver That link was helpful. Thanks! I was also trying to do the same from `npm` and run into similar issues - it looks like generally these tools weren't build to play nicely with logging.

Comment: @ibuprofen Thanks, that actually looks pretty good! It's unfortunate that the tools didn't include some sort of logging-friendly output. I'm up against similar issues with `npm` and I'm guessing all the other tools in the chain will largely be the same.

Comment: @TrivialCase Sure. Some tools have it but one have to dig deep to find what is suited. E.g. `git count-objects -v`. Others does not have it at all and in some cases they do not have anything like `--progress`, one have to use some sort of fake tty or other heuristics to get it. I use the C snip with shell wrapper as posted here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655411/140633 (The “Excluding input” section / targeting `isatty()`) for ad-hock things where I simply want the raw output.

Comment: @ibuprofen That is very handy! If you'd care to write up your comments as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Became overly long ... but found I did not have the time to clean it up now lol

Comment: Is there any difference from redirecting stdout and stderr to a file (`2>&1`)? If not that question has been asked (and answered) several hundred times at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `git` check if standard out / error is a terminal. If it is the program sprinkles the terminal output with some additional sugar in form of text indicating progress and some statistics. If not it keeps the output to standard streams to a minimum.

Internally it uses `isatty()` [as for example shown here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0785eb769886ae81e346df10e88bc49ffc0ac64e/builtin/bundle.c#L59). It is a somewhat common practice for command line programs. Not the least to strip ANSI coloring as you would not normally like to have that into a file, mess up pipe processing etc. Check for example out:

```bsh
/bin/ls --color=auto -1 # ls print column in pipe
/bin/ls --color=auto | sed -n 'l'
/bin/ls --color=always | sed -n 'l'
```

With `git` one have the option to override this by saying `-q` or `--quiet` to always suppress or `--progress` to always print. The progress output is printed to `stderr` and not (generally) meant for consumption. None the less:

```bsh
git clone --progress foo/bar.git 2>&1 | tee log
```

Other programs might not have similar options and one have to jump trough some hoops to get the data. It is done to minimize clutter etc. in for example a automated script where one still print to `stderr`, but reduce it to error messages. For example with `git`:

```bsh
$ git clone -q https://nonexistig-url.com/foo.git
fatal: https://nonexistig-url.com/foo.git/info/refs not valid: 
       is this a git repository?
$ echo $?
128
```

No progress, but one get the error message which is generally more interesting in a *after the fact* scenario. The progress of the cloning process itself is silenced.

One can sometimes get the information by other means either by post-processing or running other or additional commands. For example `git count-objects -v`.

---

#### Fake terminal

If one really want the suppressed output, and the program does not have an option for it like `git`, one option is to let the program “think” it writes to a terminal even though it does not. Various ways to achieve this; one way I use for ad-hock things where I simply want it for what ever reason is to replace the [systems `isatty()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) with one [that always return true](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655411/140633).

```bsh
echo 'int isatty(int fd) { return 1; }' | \
gcc -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o faketty.so -xc -

strip faketty.so
chmod 400 faketty.so
```

Used with a wrapper script `faketty` as:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/faketty.so "$@"
```

And used as:

```
faketty git clone foo
```

It does, as code show, not do any file descriptor checking etc. and merely a hack.

---

#### Issues with begotten data

The `git clone` command does not color the output, but it show progress. The way this is done is by repeatedly overwriting the same line in the terminal. It typically writes:

```
Cloning into 'foo'...\n
remote: Enumerating objects: 236, done.        \n
\rReceiving objects:   0% (1/236)   
\rReceiving objects:   1% (3/236)   
\rReceiving objects:   2% (5/236)   
...
\rReceiving objects:  79% (187/236)   
\rremote: Total 236 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 236        \n
...
\rReceiving objects:  99% (234/236)   
\rReceiving objects: 100% (236/236)   
\rReceiving objects: 100% (236/236), 79.45 MiB | 104.73 MiB/s, done.\n
...
```

Here the `\r`, as in Carriage Return, tells the terminal to move the cursor to *start of line* as opposed to `\n`, as in Line Feed / End of Line, which moves the cursor to the start of *next line*.

As a result each write *overwrites* the previous line until the `remote: Total 236 …` line which is ended by `\n` and the process continues on next line resulting in something like this for the viewer:

```
Cloning into 'foo'...
remote: Total 236 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 236        
Receiving objects: 100% (236/236), 79.45 MiB | 104.73 MiB/s, done.
...
```

including the visual progress for each write. As for this case a simple `cat` of the log will look OK as the terminal interpret the carriage returns, but a `sed -n l log` will show the real content. Optionally something like `sed 's/\r/\n/g' log` to show the *"lines"*.

#### Cleanup

As for ***this case***, as is, a simple pipe or post-process of log trough `sed` should suffice:

```bsh
sed 's/.*\r//'
# Optionally to trim trailing white space, either of:
sed 's/.*\r//;s/ \+$//'
sed 's/.*\r\| \+$//g'
```

It is somewhat fragile as the progress output can change between releases, versions etc. so no guarantee the information will be the same. If output has color one need to further remove these sequences.

One will loose the progress displayed (live counting) and only get the final result if the `git` command is piped trough `sed` before `tee`.